GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer Unity Не работает в WebGL
Нужен способ скопировать какой-то текст в буфер обмена. Пробовал GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer, но в сборке WebGL она не работает. Искал везде, нормального способа не нашел. Порекомендуйте код или метод.

GUIUtility.systemCopyBuffer не работает совсем, не только set, но и get. System.Windows.Clipboard не доступен, потому что Unity3D реализован на Mono, из-за чего существует systemCopyBuffer. Везде искать не нужно, это обсуждалось на фореме Unity3D. Это баг и он не исправлен.
